# Downloading .zip file from FTP in RStudio Cloud

Tags: r, ftp, zip, rcurl, rstudio-server

PROBLEM

I am trying to download a .zip file from an FTP, while keeping it and working on it in the cloud.

BACKGROUND

For company reasons, I cannot properly use R on my laptop (older version, functions blocked, etc). I am working on RStudio Cloud as an alternative.

I'm working with RCurl. From what I found I need to run getBinaryURL and then writeBin, but I cannot find a way to write a file directly into RStudio Cloud. The file itself is about 150MB and RStudio Cloud allocates 1GB of RAM per project, if this information is relevant.

```r
install.packages("RCurl")
library("RCurl")
url <- "ftp://myftp"
userpwd <- "myuser:mypass"
filenames <- getURL(url, userpwd = userpwd,ftp.use.epsv = FALSE,dirlistonly = TRUE)
filenames

#All good up to here, files in FTP are returned
#I then had problems with the normal getURL, and found after some googling that I should use getBinaryURL

file<-"ftp://myftp/filename.zip"

con<-getCurlHandle(ftp.use.epsv=FALSE,userpwd=userpwd)
raw<-getBinaryURL(file,curl = con,dirlistonly=FALSE)

#This returns a raw file, 150MB

tmp<-tempfile()
zip<-writeBin(zip,tmp)

#Returns "Error in writeBin(zip, tmp) : can only write vector objects"
```

How can I save the .zip file directly in the cloud environment?

Note: on a normal laptop I would use the command

```
writeBin(zip,'directory/file.zip')
```

and it works without problems

Answer (score 0):

Just solved - if anyone may be looking for the same reason, I simply hit tab on the selection for the path:

```
writeBin(raw,'hitTabWhenHere')
```

And went for the first option :) at least the file is there now!